# How can 2 selectboxes 1st with alphabets and the 2nd with the names that start with that alphabet

Tags: python-3.x, streamlit

How can 2 selectboxes 1st with alphabets and the 2nd with the names that start with that alphabet

1- I used the following code to create a list of CSV file names

```
path = "/home/zhamane/streamlit/Streamlit_tutorials/data"
li = [os.path.splitext(filename)[0] for filename in os.listdir(path)]
```

for example, I have 3 files in 'data' folder (all_stocks_5yr.csv, auto-mpg.csv, clean_auto_mpg.csv) it will return a list

```
[all_stocks_5yr, auto-mpg, clean_auto_mpg]
```

2- i use selectbox from stremlit to select those files

```
select_event = st.sidebar.selectbox('Choisir des indicateurs', li)
```

But I want to create 2 selectboxes 1st with a list of alphabets created from the initial alphabet for each file name (in our example)

```
[a, c]
```

and when I select for example a the 2nd list will show me all the names that start with a

3- after that i want to read the file selected with panda

```
df = pd.read_csv("path/{select_event}.csv")
```

Comment: I do not understand what you are asking. Are you trying to filter a select box using a search/filter term?

Answer (score 0):

Im uncertain what you're asking for. Im assuming that you're trying to filter your input? I've come up with the following solution.

```py
import streamlit as st
list_of_files = ["all_stocks_5yr", "auto-mpg", "clean_auto_mpg"]

st.write(list_of_files)

def should_include(item, search_term, criteria):
    if criteria == "starts with":
        return item.startswith(search_term)
    elif criteria == "contains":
        return search_term in item

search_term = st.text_input("Filter")

option = st.radio("choose filter option", ("starts with", "contains"))

new_items = [item for item in list_of_files if should_include(item, search_term, criteria = option)]
st.multiselect("Select files", list_of_files, new_items)
```

[image]